# Fortran 77 -> Fortran 90+: COMMON blocks, MPI_Bcast

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

I am refactoring F77 program to more recent Fortran standard (90 or even newer).

I have a module where some variables defined. These variables are currently put into common block, because in external subroutine all these variables are broadcasted using only one MPI_BCAST call and exploiting contiguous storage of variables in this common block.

```
module foo
  implicit none
  integer :: a,b,c,d
  real*8 :: r,t,p
  common/com/ a,b,c,d,r,t,p
end module foo

subroutine bar
  ...
  com_length = 4*4 + 3*8 ! 4 integers + 3 real(8)

  ! bcasting 'com' common block, i.e. all variables at once
  call mpi_bcast(a,com_length,mpi_byte,root,comm,ierr)
  ...
end subroutine bar
```

Problem is that length of common block `com_length` is calculated manually and error prone. If COMMON block definition is missing, debug will take ages because even valgrind won't notice OOB. 
On the other hand, calling MPI_BCAST separately for each variable will negatively impact performance.

I will appreciate your suggestions on how to refactor this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in 2 `MPI_BCAST` calls.

```
  CALL MPI_BCAST([a, b, c, d], 4, MPI_INTEGER, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  CALL MPI_BCAST([t, r, p], 3, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
```

The `4` and `3` may not be *exactly* right, but the idea is still the same: group your like-variables as an array and broadcast them.

Comment: Note that square brackets for array constructors are a feature of Fortran 2003 and may not be supported by a given compiler (though every one I've used does). You might have to use `(/ /)` instead.

Comment: Thanks! So simple. I was thinking of more complex solutions, e.g. putting everything to the derived type with SEQUENCE storage... Your solution is very elegant.

Comment: @Yossarian yes, I know this, but the idea is understandable though.

Comment: @kyle-kanos after thinking for a while, this solution will not work: a,b,c,d, ... root rank will broadcast them, but how are they set on all other processors?

Comment: @robusta: what do you mean? If you declare `INTEGER :: a, b, c, d` and `REAL(8) :: r, t, p`, then all processes will know these variables. If the `root` process is the one that defines them, then when `MPI_BCAST` is called, then all the processors will have the variables set.

Comment: @Yossarian: I often forget that `[...]` is a recent substitute for `(/.../)`. It definitely works on sunf90, gfortran, and ifort compilers that I have. Not sure about others (though I presume it still is used).

Comment: @KyleKanos: CALL MPI_BCAST([a, b, c, d], 4, MPI_INTEGER, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) will create (new) automatic array [a,b,c,d], but will not associate its storage with variables a, b, c, d. So after MPI_BCAST receiving ranks will have these variables still undefined.

Comment: @Yossarian: And you are unable to do `IF(MPI_ID > root) a = array(1)` etc because? :D

Comment: @KyleKanos: I am already doing this :) "if (mpi_id > root) ..." is even unnecessary :) on root rank it will be redundant, but we save calling mpi_comm_rank for getting mpi_id.